# Qt Event Loop and OS Messages

Tags: qt, message-queue, event-loop

Recently, I was involved in a project where we implemented a dll in QT. We ran into problems after the fact when trying to get the DLL written in QT working with a non-QT application because of lack of having an event loop in our main thread. We figured out a way to get this working without needing an event queue, however, there is concern that the lack of an event queue will result in the DLL's internal message queue being overflowed with OS generated messages. This concept is new to me and I was hoping someone could explain to me more whether or not this is a real concern and what types of OS originated messages are inserted into an applications message queue.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, a thread must own at least one window in order for it to get a message queue and to receive messages. A window is an OS resource, not something that you necessarily see on screen. It *optionally* can be visible. So yes, if you create one or more windows in a thread, and you don't process their messages, the message queues might eventually get full. And that's about it, nothing untoward happens afterwards. The windows, if visible, will appear to be frozen/stuck, otherwise you can't even tell if there's a problem. All is good. You're using up a bit of memory for the full message queues, but it's not an astronomical amount at all.

With a full message queue that you never intend to empty, `PostMessage` will return a failure, and of course a synchronous `SendMessage` will wait forever. That's expected but not a problem, because the OS message sources practically never use `SendMessage` to implement message broadcast, so you won't freeze some important system-wide service by having a thread with a full message queue.

On OS X, events come from event sources that do require an explicit operation to attach to a run loop. If you don't have a run loop with input sources attached, and there are no selectors to be performed on that thread, you're again - good. If not, the event queue's size will be limited, and once full, no more events will be appended.

TL;DR: An OS will send messages to you only if you care for them. If you don't, you won't get any. It's not as if the OS was "out there to get you for not listening" :)